# Usage of myBoolean = !myBoolean

Tags: security, button, boolean, vaadin, setter

I've seen this kind of statement a few times in Java code. For example when wanting to set a button NOT visible in Vaadin framework (or equivalent):

```
boolean access = Authorizator.isAdmin();
access = !access;
saveButton.setVisible(access);
```

Why not just do it like this:

```
boolean access = Authorizator.isAdmin();    
if(!access) {
    saveButton.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: where u saw this exactly? maybe its developer's prerence to write code in his own way, I don't see any hidden cause here.

Comment: If the non-visible button was created earlier and the code is re-run after a user change, the first option would make the button visible again while the second would not, even though user should be able to see it.

Comment: However this myBoolean=!myBoolean does not affect this and imo is generally not a very good practice. Either adding a method isNotAdmin or just access = !Authorization.isAdmin would be clearer to me. I guess it depends on the developers preference as Imran said.

Answer (score 2):

Your second example is not the same. It ONLY sets the button invisible, never sets it visible. The cleanest (IMHO) and functionally equal to the first would be

```
saveButton.setVisible(!Authorizer.isAdmin());
```

Comment: I think you meant to say the first example, not second?

Comment: well I meant to say both examples are functionally different. Assuming the first example is the "current" situation, your proposed alternative (the second example) is changing the functionality, i.e. second only hides it, while the first may either show or hide it.